# Check CMake Cache Variable in Toolchain File

Tags: cmake

I'm having trouble setting a configuration variable via the command line. I can't determine it from the system, so I expect the user to specify:

```
cmake -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=../android.toolchain -DANDROID_ABI:STRING="arm64" ..
```

Inside my `android.toolchain`, I have the following:

```
message(STATUS "Android ABI: ${ANDROID_ABI}")
if( "${ANDROID_ABI}" STREQUAL "" )
   message(FATAL_ERROR "Please specifiy ABI at cmake call -DANDROID_ABI:STRING=armeabi or -DANDROID_ABI:STRING=arm64")
endif()
```

No matter what, it fails at this line EVEN THOUGH it prints out the correct arm64:

```
 -- Android ABI: arm64
CMake Error at yaml-cpp/android.toolchain:45 (message):
Please specifiy ABI at cmake call -DANDROID_ABI:STRING=armeabi or -DANDROID_ABI:STRING=arm64
```

Could anyone direct me to what I'm doing wrong?

---

I think this has to do with:

- -D adds a cache variable instead of a normal variable
- This is in a toolchain file... it seems to ignore cache variables

Any thoughts or suggestions?

Comment: try `if (NOT ANDROID_ABI) ...`.

Comment: One of the developers suggests global properties might be a good workaround: https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/issues/16170#note_135718

Answer (score 10):

I don't pretend to fully understand what's going on behind the scenes, but here's a workaround that works for me:

```cmake
# Problem: CMake runs toolchain files multiple times, but can't read cache variables on some runs.
# Workaround: On first run (in which cache variables are always accessible), set an intermediary environment variable.

if (FOO)
    # Environment variables are always preserved.
    set(ENV{_FOO} "${FOO}")
else ()
    set(FOO "$ENV{_FOO}")
endif ()
```

Comment: Behind the scene: the problem appears when *cmake* tries to determine compiler or compiler options, and in this case it uses toolchain file without cache variables reading. Your solution seems like good workaround

Answer (score 0):

CMake 3.6 introduces variable [CMAKE_TRY_COMPILE_PLATFORM_VARIABLES](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_TRY_COMPILE_PLATFORM_VARIABLES.html) which contains a list of variables, automatically passed from the main project to the project, created with `try_compile`.

A toolchain may add its variables to that list, so they could be extracted in a subproject:

```
message(STATUS "Android ABI: ${ANDROID_ABI}")
if( "${ANDROID_ABI}" STREQUAL "" )
   message(FATAL_ERROR "Please specifiy ABI at cmake call -DANDROID_ABI:STRING=armeabi or -DANDROID_ABI:STRING=arm64")
endif()

# propagate the variable into "inner" subprojects.
list(APPEND CMAKE_TRY_COMPILE_PLATFORM_VARIABLES "ANDROID_ABI")
```

Caveats:

1. This approach affects only to **source** flow of [try_compile](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/try_compile.html) command. It won't work when `try_compile` is used for create **fully-fledged** CMake project with signature

   ```
   try_compile(<resultVar> <bindir> <srcdir> <projectName> ...)
   ```

   (Approach with setting environment variable, as described in the [@sorbet answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29997033/3440745), works perfectly in this case.)
2. This approach won't work for a subproject, created with `ExternalProject_Add`.
   (Approach with setting environment variable fails in that case too.)