# How to pass a variable from command line to a CMake Toolhain file?

Tags: cmake

Is there a way to pass a variable to a toolchain file when invoking cmake?

For example, I have the following toolchain file:

```
message("FOO = ${FOO}")
```

I have tried the following, but it did not work. The variable is not set in the toolchain file.

```
cmake <src-dir> -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=<toolchain-file> -DFOO="bar" -B <build-dir>
```

---

What I am actually trying to achieve is passing a path to the toolchain file. And I can't modify the main CMakeLists.txt in .

Comment: Did you try `cmake <src-dir> -DFOO="bar" -B <build-dir>`

Comment: @ThomasSablik Yes, same issue.

Comment: Which version of CMake do you use? What is `-B`? How do you set the path to the toolchain file?

Comment: Related (or the same problem?): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28613394/check-cmake-cache-variable-in-toolchain-file. Please, show toolchain specification (`-DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=...` or so) in your command line.

Comment: @ThomasSablik I am using cmake verison 3.5.2 on Windows. With `-B` I am setting the build directory. I am setting the path to the toolchain file with `-D` (forgot to mention it in the question, sorry).

Comment: Parameter `-B` does not work for me as expected. It sets the source path and not the build path. The order of `<src-dir>` and `-DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=<toolchain-file>` is wrong. Try `cmake -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=<toolchain-file> <src-dir> -DFOO="bar"` as in my answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to set the path to your toolchain file with `-DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE`. The following works for me (cmake3 version 3.12.0):

ToolChain.cmake:

```
message("Toolchain file loaded with path: ${FOO}")
```

CMakeLists.txt empty

```
cmake -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=./ToolChain.cmake . -DFOO=/path
```

Output is:

```
Toolchain file loaded with path: /path
```

The order of `<src-path>` and `-DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=./ToolChain.cmake` is important.

```
cmake . -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=./ToolChain.cmake -DFOO=/path
```

doesn't work.