# Parameterizing custom CMake toolchain

Tags: c++, cmake, cross-compiling

I'm writing CMake toolchain files for cross-compilation.

I've got several toolchains, that differ very slightly. I'd like to create a single file for cmake that describes all toolchains and have users to specify them from command line: `cmake -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=/path/to/toolchain.cmake -DTOOLCHAIN_NAME=<name>`

However, it seems that `TOOLCHAIN_NAME` sometimes becomes an empty string.

Here is the example of the toolchain file:

```
set(tools /opt/toolchains/Custom/toolchains/toolchain)
set(sdk   /opt/toolchains/Custom/platforms/)

message(STATUS "toolchain_name ${TOOLCHAIN_NAME}")
if(NOT TOOLCHAIN_NAME) 
    message(SEND_ERROR "Please specify toolchain name in -DTOOLCHAIN_NAME parameter")
endif()

set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Generic)
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR ARM)

# further processing
```

Then I call CMake:

```
mkdir build
cd build
cmake .. -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=../cmake/toolchain.cmake -DTOOLCHAIN_NAME=proc-os-gnueabi-gcc_6_3
```

And get following output with errors:

```
-- toolchain name proc-os-gnueabi-gcc_6_3
-- toolchain name proc-os-gnueabi-gcc_6_3
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 6.3.1
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 6.3.1
-- Check for working C compiler: /opt/toolchains/.../bin/arm-os-gnueabi-gcc
CMake Error at /home/user/project/cmake/toolchain.cmake:59 (message):
  Please specify toolchain name in -DTOOLCHAIN_NAME parameter

Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /home/user/project/build/CMakeFiles/3.15.4/CMakeSystem.cmake:6 (include)
  /home/user/project/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CMakeLists.txt:2 (project)


CMake Error at /usr/local/share/cmake-3.15/Modules/CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake:44 (try_compile):
  Failed to configure test project build system.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:15 (project)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/user/project/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/user/project/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

CMakeOutput.log and CMakeError.log contain messages, saying that the compiler didn't find some libraries.

If I open generated file `/home/user/project/build/CMakeFiles/3.15.4/CMakeSystem.cmake` I can see the following

```
set(CMAKE_HOST_SYSTEM "Linux-4.2.0-27-generic")
set(CMAKE_HOST_SYSTEM_NAME "Linux")
set(CMAKE_HOST_SYSTEM_VERSION "4.2.0-27-generic")
set(CMAKE_HOST_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR "x86_64")

include("/home/user/project/cmake/toolchain.cmake")

set(CMAKE_SYSTEM "Generic")
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME "Generic")
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_VERSION "")
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR "ARM")

set(CMAKE_CROSSCOMPILING "TRUE")

set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_LOADED 1)
```

According to CMake manual, its `-D` argument is used to specify cache entries.

I conclude from the output above that supplied toolchain file is processed by CMake at least 3 times. During first two times there were proper cache entries, and at the third run they were absent.

So, how can I avoid code duplication for toolchain files?

UPD. After reading [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52072356/3987854) I've tried several permutations of CMake command line parameters: specifying source path after toolchain but before options, specifying it after options, explicitly specifying source path and build path with `-S` and `-B` options. Nothing has helped.

Comment: Perhaps, you are running into the issue described in the response [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52072356/3987854).

Comment: Thank you for pointing it out. I've tried and failed. Question was updated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I conclude from the output above that supplied toolchain file is processed by CMake at least 3 times. First two times there were proper cache entries, and at the third run they were absent.

Yes, this is very good observation. Technically, only the first toolchain invocation at the `project()` call is guarantee to see the CACHE entries (created with `-D` parameters to `cmake` or with `set()` commands prior to the `project()` call).

One approach for pass CACHE entries between the different toolchain invocations is storing them in the **environment variables**:

Example below uses `MY_TOOLCHAIN_NAME` environment variable as a storage for `TOOLCHAIN_NAME` CMake variable.

```
if(DEFINED ENV{MY_TOOLCHAIN_NAME})
    # Environment variable is set.
    if (TOOLCHAIN_NAME)
        # CMake variable is set too.
        # It is up to your which one to use.
        # Uncomment line below for prefer environment variable to CMake one.
        # set(TOOLCHAIN_NAME $ENV{MY_TOOLCHAIN_NAME})
    else ()
        # CMake variable is not set. Use environment one.
        set(TOOLCHAIN_NAME $ENV{MY_TOOLCHAIN_NAME})
    endif()
else()
    # Environment variable is not set.
    if (TOOLCHAIN_NAME)
        # But CMake variable is set.
        # Store it into the environment and use it.
        set(ENV{MY_TOOLCHAIN_NAME} ${TOOLCHAIN_NAME})
    else()
        # Neither environment nor CMake variable is set.
        message(SEND_ERROR "Please specify toolchain name in -DTOOLCHAIN_NAME parameter")
    endif()
endif()
```

If you have several "tuning" variables, you may write a macro for all above steps and apply(call) this macro for every variable you need.

Comment: > One approach for pass CACHE entries between the different toolchain invocations 
Do you know other ones? Could you share? This approach works perfectly, but I'd like to know more :)

Comment: "Do you know other ones?" - Unfortunately, no. Actually, I have seen this approach (only the approach, not the code) in some cmake mailing, and after some considerations I found it to be the "right" one. If one knows the right way, why he/she is needed another way?:) Especially in the case of such complex topic as a CMake toolchains, which documentation leaves much to be desired.