# How to set CMAKE_SYSROOT correctly in CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE

Tags: android, cmake, clang

I currently trouble with writing CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE for and Android project

```
set(CMAKE_SYSROOT "${ANDROID_TOOLCHAIN_ROOT}/sysroot")
```

This will expand to `${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/external/cmdline-tools/latest/../.sdk/ndk/25.2.9519653/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot`. This is an existed directory created when I use `sdkmanager`.

Now I got an error

```
-- CMAKE_SYSROOT /home/user/demo_project/external/cmdline-tools/latest/../.sdk/ndk/25.2.9519653/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot
-- Android: Selected Clang toolchain 'aarch64-linux-android-clang' with GCC toolchain ''
-- The C compiler identification is Clang 14.0.7
-- The CXX compiler identification is Clang 14.0.7
-- Check for working C compiler: /home/user/demo_project/external/cmdline-tools/latest/../.sdk/ndk/25.2.9519653/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/clang
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/Platform/Android-Initialize.cmake:31 (message):
  Android: The system root directory needed for the selected Android version
  and architecture does not exist:

    /home/user/demo_project/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/external/cmdline-tools/latest/../.sdk/ndk/25.2.9519653/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot
```

what I do is

```
~/demo_project$ mkdir build
~/demo_project$ cd build
~/demo_project$ cmake ../ -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=../tool/buildtools/cmake_toolchain/android.cmake
```

What did I do wrong with the CMAKE_SYSROOT?
I did notice that the path `/home/user/demo_project/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/external/cmdline-tools/latest/../.sdk/ndk/25.2.9519653/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot` is not quite the same with what I got if I `message(STATUS "CMAKE_SYSROOT ${CMAKE_SYSROOT})`

Full CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE is below:

```
set(HOST_TAG "linux-x86_64")
set(ANDROID_API 31)
set(SDK "../.sdk")
set(ANDROID_CMD ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/external/cmdline-tools/latest) #for android_sdkmanager_install macro to work, set this
set(ANDROID_PACKAGES "")
set(NDK_PATH ${ANDROID_CMD}/${SDK}/ndk/25.2.9519653)
set(CMAKE_ANDROID_NDK ${NDK_PATH})
set(CMAKE_ANDROID_API ${ANDROID_API})
set(ANDROID_TARGET aarch64-linux-android${ANDROID_API})
set(CMAKE_ANDROID_NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION clang)

set(ANDROID_TARGET_TRIPLE "aarch64-linux-android")
set(ANDROID_TARGET_ARCH "armv8")
set(CMAKE_ANDROID_ARCH_ABI "arm64-v8a")

set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Android)

SET(ANDROID_TOOLCHAIN_ROOT ${NDK_PATH}/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64)
set(CMAKE_SYSROOT "${ANDROID_TOOLCHAIN_ROOT}/sysroot")
# Disable some features that are not available on Android
SET(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PROGRAM NEVER)
SET(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_LIBRARY ONLY)
SET(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_INCLUDE ONLY)
```

I wrote a script to setup a ndk via `sdkmanager`:

```
SCRIPT_DIR="$( dirname -- "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}"; )"
SCRIPT_DIR=$(realpath $SCRIPT_DIR)

ANDROID_API=31

cd $SCRIPT_DIR/../external/cmdline-tools/latest/

echo Handle android lincenses
yes | ./bin/sdkmanager --sdk_root=../.sdk --licenses

sdk_install() {
    PACKAGE_NAME=$1
    echo Handle package "$PACKAGE_NAME"
    ./bin/sdkmanager --sdk_root=../.sdk --install "$PACKAGE_NAME"

}

sdk_install "build-tools;34.0.0-rc4"
sdk_install "ndk;25.2.9519653"
sdk_install "platforms;android-$ANDROID_API"

PLATFORMS_DIR=$(realpath $SCRIPT_DIR/../external/cmdline-tools/.sdk/platforms)
ln -sf $PLATFORMS_DIR ../.sdk/ndk/25.2.9519653/platforms
```

Comment: I don't think that referencing `CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR` in the toolchain file is a good idea. Note, that a toolchain file is actually used not only for build your project itself, but for additional projects created by CMake for check different properties of your compilation environment. Probably, this is a reason of the error message you got: For some additional project source dir is `/home/user/demo_project/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp`, so calculations of CMAKE_SYSROOT use that value instead of `/home/user/demo_project`.

Comment: You could design your toolchain file to **save** value of e.g. `NDK_PATH` on the first invocation and **load** that value on next invocations: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62796383/3440745

Answer (score 0):

I'm surprised with my solution. But moving from CMake 3.10.2 to 3.26.4 solves the problem. This is seem to be previous CMake version is not compatible with newer Android packages.