# CMake: pass variables to custom toolchain file

Tags: c++, cmake, cross-compiling

I am creating a toolchain file for a gcc-based C compiler for a non-popular platform. I would like users to pass a path to compiler root directory, while a toolchain file will set up all the paths to c/c++/ar/whatever, set proper compile flags.

My toolchain file starts with this check:

```
IF(NOT TOOLCHAIN_PREFIX)
     MESSAGE(FATAL_ERROR "No TOOLCHAIN_PREFIX specified")
ENDIF()
```

All other paths are calculated based on TOOLCHAIN_PREFIX variable, which I want users to be passed as a parameter to cmake (e.g. cmake -DTOOLCHAIN_PREFIX=/path/to/compiler/root ..)

Problem: during configuration process, cmake gets to 'Detecting C compiler ABI info' step, and runs compilation of a test program, and passes there a toolchain file. The issue is that my variable TOOLCHAIN_PREFIX is not passed there. As result I get error and configuration process stops.

What is the proper way of passing my TOOLCHAIN_PREFIX parameter to the nested try_compile() operations?

Alternative question: what is the proper way of building toolchain files so that it can search for a compiler at a specific path?

UPDATE: Here is a minimal example, reproducing the issue:

CMakeLists.txt

```
set(CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE Toolchain.cmake)
project(Test CXX)
```

Toolchain.cmake

```
if(NOT TOOLCHAIN_PREFIX)
    message(FATAL_ERROR "No TOOLCHAIN_PREFIX specified")
endif()
```

Output:

```
D:\Projects\Test\build>cmake -DTOOLCHAIN_PREFIX=abcde ..
-- Selecting Windows SDK version 10.0.17763.0 to target Windows 10.0.19043.
-- The CXX compiler identification is MSVC 19.29.30136.0
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
CMake Error at D:/Projects/Test/Toolchain.cmake:2 (message):
  No TOOLCHAIN_PREFIX specified
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  D:/Projects/Test/build/CMakeFiles/3.18.1/CMakeSystem.cmake:6 (include)
  D:/Projects/Test/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CMakeLists.txt:3 (project)
```

Comment: Did you try with a fresh build directory? `test program, and passes there a toolchain file. The issue is that my variable TOOLCHAIN_PREFIX is not passed there` Wait, what do you understand is a "toolchain file"? Why would the _test program_ need `TOOLCHAIN_PREFIX` CMake variable set? How are you checking if it is "passed"?

Comment: Yes, I tried with a fresh directory. I am pretty sure test program does not need TOOLCHAIN_PREFIX. But once I set CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE this toolchain file will be passed to whatever is tried to compile with TRY_COMPILE (particularly it fails when CMake tries to understand compiler ABI). And once toolchain file is loaded during TRY_COMPILE, it fails on checking TOOLCHAIN_PREFIX.

Comment: As for 'what do you understand is a toolchain file". My understanding that the toolchain file shall set paths to compiler, binutils, etc. But assuming that the toolchain can be located in non-standard folder I must specify somehow where it is located. Is there any other way to hint CMake where to search for a compiler?

Comment: `this toolchain file will be passed to whatever is tried to compile with TRY_COMPILE` No, toolchain file is not used, the variables that the toolchain file has set are used. Please post verbatim the error messages. How do you know that "TOOLCHAIN_PREFIX is not passed there"? what do you mean by that? What do you mean by "passing" a CMake variable? `my TOOLCHAIN_PREFIX parameter to the nested try_compile()` `try_compile` does not use TOOLCHAIN_PREFIX variable, and also there's no way to "pass" anything to `try_compile`. I do not know what you mean.

Comment: I used --trace cmake switch to understand how it processes the toolchain file under the hood. First, CMakeDetermineSystem.cmake (Bundled with CMake) sets the INCLUDE_CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE_IF_REQUIRED variable, which is then burned into CMakeSystem.cmake.in, including the toolchain file. Then this CMakeSystem.cmake is somehow passed to nested makes when try_compile is executed. And that is the problem.

Comment: See a question update - I created a minimal example reproducing the issue

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parameterizing custom CMake toolchain](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62795924/23715), which in turn duplicates [Check CMake Cache Variable in Toolchain File](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28613394/23715)